# How do I use jQuery.map to recursively modify nested objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion

How do I recursively modify nested objects using jQuery.map (or vanilla JS)?

```
// Original Object
var data = [{
    name: 'Parent',
    children: [{
        name: 'Child',
        children: [{
            name: 'ChildChild'
        }]
    }]
}];

// Resulting Object
var data = [{
    name: 'Parent',
    text: 'Parent',
    children: [{
        name: 'Child',
        text: 'Child',
        children: [{
            name: 'ChildChild',
            text: 'ChildChild'
        }]
    }]
}];
```

I currently do this within the top level using jQuery.map like so, but don't know how to achieve this recursively.

```
$.map(data, function(obj){
    return $.extend(obj, {text: obj.name});
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/minlare/0p0zb8vw/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `map()` to modify an array; it's designed to create a subset of an array. To modify an array use `each()` or any other standard looping mechanism.

With that in mind, you can use `$.each()` in this case to recurse through the objects at each level of the array. Try this:

```
function setText(arr) {
    $.each(arr, function(i, obj) {
        obj.text = obj.name;
        if (obj.children && obj.children.length) {
            setText(obj.children);
        }
    });
}
setText(data);
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/0p0zb8vw/3/)